# Al crear EntityManagerFactory con la unidad de Persistencia el programa se detiene JAVA

Tags: java, jpa

tengo un problema con mi aplicacion web que estoy desarrolando usando JPA, la cual funcionaba bien hasta ayer. 
 Con ayuda de DEBUG de Java he ejecutado linea a linea y me di cuenta que el problema algunas veces esta en el `EntityManagerFactory`, y otras veces en el controlador del JPA de la entidad al pasar por el metodo `getEntityManager().` Al decir problema me refiero a que simplemente despues de ejecutar esa linea de codigo no avanza a la siguiente ,simplemente no hace nada el programa.

No se por que pasa esto. Aqui esta mi JPA controller, lo cree con el asistente que trae netbeans.

El método que ocupo es `findEmpresaEntities()`

```
public class UsuarioJpaController implements Serializable {

public UsuarioJpaController(UserTransaction utx, EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    this.utx = utx;
    this.emf = emf;
}
private UserTransaction utx = null;
private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {

    return emf.createEntityManager();

}

public void create(Usuario usuario) throws RollbackFailureException, Exception {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        utx.begin();
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.persist(usuario);
        utx.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        try {
            utx.rollback();
        } catch (Exception re) {
            throw new RollbackFailureException("An error occurred attempting to roll back the transaction.", re);
        }
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}

public void edit(Usuario usuario) throws NonexistentEntityException, RollbackFailureException, Exception {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        utx.begin();
        em = getEntityManager();
        usuario = em.merge(usuario);
        utx.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        try {
            utx.rollback();
        } catch (Exception re) {
            throw new RollbackFailureException("An error occurred attempting to roll back the transaction.", re);
        }
        String msg = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
        if (msg == null || msg.length() == 0) {
            Integer id = usuario.getIdusuario();
            if (findUsuario(id) == null) {
                throw new NonexistentEntityException("The usuario with id " + id + " no longer exists.");
            }
        }
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}

public void destroy(Integer id) throws NonexistentEntityException, RollbackFailureException, Exception {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        utx.begin();
        em = getEntityManager();
        Usuario usuario;
        try {
            usuario = em.getReference(Usuario.class, id);
            usuario.getIdusuario();
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException enfe) {
            throw new NonexistentEntityException("The usuario with id " + id + " no longer exists.", enfe);
        }
        em.remove(usuario);
        utx.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        try {
            utx.rollback();
        } catch (Exception re) {
            throw new RollbackFailureException("An error occurred attempting to roll back the transaction.", re);
        }
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}

public List<Usuario> findUsuarioEntities() {
    return findUsuarioEntities(true, -1, -1);
}

public List<Usuario> findUsuarioEntities(int maxResults, int firstResult) {
    return findUsuarioEntities(false, maxResults, firstResult);
}

private List<Usuario> findUsuarioEntities(boolean all, int maxResults, int firstResult) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(Usuario.class));
        Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
        if (!all) {
            q.setMaxResults(maxResults);
            q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
        }
        return q.getResultList();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

public Usuario findUsuario(Integer id) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        return em.find(Usuario.class, id);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

public int getUsuarioCount() {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        Root<Usuario> rt = cq.from(Usuario.class);
        cq.select(em.getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

}

En esta clase es donde creo el `EMF`

```
public class BusinessProcedure {

public static boolean validateUser(UsuarioTO miUsuario){

    boolean flag = false;

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ControlAdministrativoPU");

    UsuarioJpaController usuarioDAO = new UsuarioJpaController(null,emf);

    List<Usuario> lista = usuarioDAO.findUsuarioEntities();

    for (Usuario u :lista) {

                if(miUsuario.getRfc().equals(u.getRfc()) && miUsuario.getPass().equals(u.getPass()) && miUsuario.getUsuario().equals(u.getUsuario()) ) {flag = true; break;}
                else flag = false;

            }

    emf.close();

    return flag;

}
```

Aquie esta Persitence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="ControlAdministrativoPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:app/MySQLControl</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Alguien sabra como resolver esto, ¿algunas recomendaciones?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Si lo dejas lanza un timeout?

Answer (score 2):

Hola te recomiendo que no uses del todo el ayudante de Netbeans , ahora si lo usas esté a mi modo de ver trae mucha basura, lo que realizo es quitar toda esa basura que no uso, por ejemplo el UserTransaction.

La creación y ejecución del EntityManagerFactory y EntityManager, se debe realizar en la capa de negocio siempre , hay una manera más cómoda de implementarla y crearla que es:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "ColegioPU")
private EntityManager em;
```

Pero te dejo el ejemplo, con la creación de un curso y el listado de los mismos , usando el ayudante de Netbeans para que estés familiarizado con el mismo.

```
public class CursoJpaController implements Serializable {


public CursoJpaController() {
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ColegioPU");
}

private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}

public Curso registrar(Curso curso) throws Exception{
    EntityManager em = null;
    Curso cur = new Curso();
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(curso);
        cur = em.merge(curso);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("creates: "+ e.getMessage());
    }finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
    return cur;
}
public List<Curso> findCursoEntities() {
    return findCursoEntities(true, -1, -1);
}

public List<Curso> findCursoEntities(int maxResults, int firstResult) {
    return findCursoEntities(false, maxResults, firstResult);
}

private List<Curso> findCursoEntities(boolean all, int maxResults, int firstResult) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(Curso.class));
        Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
        if (!all) {
            q.setMaxResults(maxResults);
            q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
        }
        return q.getResultList();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

public Curso findCurso(Integer id) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        return em.find(Curso.class, id);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

}
```

Para la persistencia debes tener incluidas siempre las entidades mapeadas desde la base de datos, adicional el pool de conexión si no estás realizando la misma por JDNI(configurandola desde el servidor de aplicaciones), entonces debes indicar todos los parámetros de conexión , te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="ColegioPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:app/Prog2</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.colegio.co.entities.Alumno</class>
    <class>com.colegio.co.entities.Curso</class>
    <class>com.colegio.co.entities.Tipos</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/colegio"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Si no entiendes algo simplemente pregunta , ya que es gratis :).